# Rails design for database record (employment) history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

So, I have a Rails application that tracks employees.  We want to track the employment history over time.   We'd like to be able to do the following sorts of queries:

1. Search employees by their current status (salary, manager, title etc.)
2. Search for remployees by status as of a particular date
3. Search for employees who ever matched a condition

We don't mind the historical queries being significantly slower, even maybe 2 orders of magnitude slower.

This history is different from an audit trail - an audit trail is the history of the data, so an audit trail will tell you "what salary was stored for employee X on date Y," but it won't let you correct that older data if it is wrong.

[We are also using audit trails for auditing purposes, but I think of the logic for audit trails as providing an almost orthogonal design requirement.]

Is there a known database design pattern for best implementing this kind of history?  Or a site where I can find discussions of the various "obvious" designs and the trade-offs?  Any Rails plugins?

Rails 2.3.5 with Ruby 1.8.7, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) claims to support this type of version management. It would seem to handle your requirements (1) and (2) easily -- not sure about (3), you might need to do some heavy lifting to get a query that searched across models and versions at the same time.

> This history is different from an audit trail

Meaning that you need the ability to make changes to old versions -- I doubt that is supported, and it seems problematic to implement if you also need this to act as an audit trail.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking for an audit trail (which can be seen as a narrative history of th data in the system,) but rather a tool that tracks current and past "real" values.  So I want to know "what was the salary of Jim on 10/15/2010?"  Not, "What was th value of Jim's salary stored in the database on 10/15/2010."  In particular, then, I want to be able to import, enter, and update data for past periods.